# Unable to use the methods next_sibling or next_elt with twig_handlers using XML::Twig

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-twig

I am still new with using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig).

From the main program I look for the elements with attribute `@method="create"`

In the subroutine `player`, I want to find the *next* element/sibling with attribute `@method="modify"`.

Both of these methods fail in subroutine `player` with the error `Can't call method "gi" on an undefined value`

```
my $modif1=$valeur->next_sibling('[@method="modify"]')

my $modif2=$valeur->next_elt('[@method="modify"]')->parent
```

Example of input.xwo:

```
<top id="World">

  <middle id="France" method="create">
  </middle>

  <middle id="Germany" method="modify">
  </middle>

</top>
```

My simple code:

```
#!/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig= new XML::Twig( 
  twig_handlers => {
    '[@method="create"]' => \&player
  } 
);                    

$twig->parsefile("input.xwo");
$twig->purge;  

sub player { 

  my ($twig, $valeur) = @_;                     

  my $modif1 = $valeur->next_sibling('[@method="modify"]');
  my $modif2 = $valeur->next_elt('[@method="modify"]')->parent;
  print "\nnextELT=" . $modif->gi . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please *always* `use strict` at the top of your programs and declare variables using `my` at their first point of use. There is no point in both `use warnings` and the `-w` command-line option. The first is preferable.

When the twig handler for the `<middle method="create">` element is called, the sibling that you require, `<middle method="modify">` hasn't been processed. It can't be found because it isn't yet in the `XML::Twig` parse tree.

You must either read the entire XML structure and process it afterwards, or write a handler for the element that encloses *both* the `create` and `modify` elements.

This program does the latter.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig= XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => {
    top => \&player
  } 
);                    

$twig->parsefile('input.xwo');
$twig->purge;  

sub player { 

  my ($twig, $valeur) = @_;                   

  my $create = $valeur->first_child('[@method="create"]');
  return unless $create;

  my $modify = $create->next_sibling('[@method="modify"]');
  return unless $modify;

  printf "\nnextELT = %s\n", $modify->gi;

  $twig->purge;
}
```

---

**Update**

This alternative reads the entire XML tree and extracts the data from it afterwards. It starts by finding *all* elements in the tree that have a `method` attribute equal to `'create'`, and then finds the following sibling of each of them with a `method` attribute of `'modify'`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig= XML::Twig->new;

$twig->parsefile('input.xwo');

my @creates = $twig->get_xpath('//*[@method="create"]');

foreach my $create (@creates) {
  my $modify = $create->next_sibling('[@method="modify"]');
  next unless $modify;
  printf "\nnextELT = %s\n", $modify->gi;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Borodin for those solution. But for the solution with `twig_handlers`, how would you find also all the elements in the tree ?  In the code you wrote, you put `top` as the first branch to search.  I will need find all elements preferably using twig_handlers

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the way `XML::Twig` is meant to work. Setting a handle on *every* element would entail a huge amount of coding that is almost certainly unnecessary. How big is your XML file? If it up to a few KB then it is best to read the entire structure into memory and process it from there. If you explain the problem you have to solve then we can help further

Comment: so the twig_handlers (asynchronous queue) to "query each searched Element" will consume much more CPU/memory than "reading the whole file + get_xpath" (your second solution) ? If so I will stick with your second solution and revise my previous code based on twig_handlers.

Comment: A twig handler is called *synchronously* as the XML is parsed. When an element's closing tag is encountered the corresponding handler is called and then the parsing continues. The idea is to split the data into manageable chunks, not to code a handler for every element you need to process. Without seeing your real data and understanding your application I can't help you further. I suggest you raise a new question giving more information.